# Angular4 Routing: Force Navigation By Bypassing Route Guard

Tags: angular, angular4-router

When my users have dirty changes on a screen, I have a route guard to prompt them to save or discard when they try to navigate away.

However, if I am logging them out due to inactivity, I want to force navigation and bypass the route guard (by discarding their changes), in order to ensure that their screen is blanked.

How can I bypass route guards?

Answer (score 11):

My solution was as follows:

My `logout` method after successfully logging out, redirects the app to the `/login` route:

```
@Injectable
export class AuthService {
  // ...
  logout () {
    // do logout
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

My guard is then as follows:

```
@Injectable
export class DiscardChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<MyComponent> {

  canDeactivate(component: MyComponent, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if (nextState.url === '/login') {
      return true; // bypass checks if we are trying to go to /login
    }

    // perform regular checks here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how you can force a bypass on a **per-navigation basis**. In my case I was navigating back to the account dashboard after the user submits a form with account info.

Ideally you would check for unsaved changes in the form and bypass based on that, but my forms don't have that feature yet.

form component:

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { state: { bypassFormGuard: true } })
```

router guard:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ExitFormGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {

   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
      if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state?.bypassFormGuard) {
         return true
      }

      // perform normal checks
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is a good idea, but it could be shorter by using the optional chaining with ?. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining    if (navObject?.extras?.state?.bypassFormGuard) { return true; }

Comment: @Pierre Good point, I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

My goal was to bypass route guards without touching every route guard in the app, but I was unable to do that. Ultimately I created a new `RouteBypassService` to inject into every route guard.  `RouteBypassService` implements `shouldBypass`, which returns true if the route guard should allow navigation for some overriding out of band reason, such as authorization. In my case `shouldBypass` returns true iff there is no user signed in. (After they sign out, we let them get off the screen no matter what).

It's not ideal because every author of a route guard has to affirmatively remember to add the bypass, but it's not terribly entangling.

Answer (score 0):

I create something like a white list to write every route I want to bypass guard

white-list.ts

```
export const WhiteListedRoutes: string[] = [
  '/route1',
  '/route2',
];
```

Then in the guard something like:

```
import { WhiteListedRoutes } from './white-list';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(_next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
    const route = state.url.split('?')[0];
    const queryParams = _route.queryParams;
    const isWhiteListed = WhiteListedRoutes.findIndex((r: string) => r === route) >= 0;

    return this.status || isWhiteListed || this.router.navigate(['/'], { state: { r: route }, queryParams } );
  }
}
```